# autoNumber in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

i want to migrate from VB6 to VB.NET, but still rookie. how to make autoNumber procedure works like
code in VB6 in VB.NET (VB2012), below my code so far.

below my previous code in VB6, this code will work when addbutton_click, it will display CDEUSR005, since there are 4 record in table before, CDEUSR001, CDEUSR002, CDEUSR003, CDEUSR004.
[Image sample that works in VB6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvqHX.png)

```
Sub autoNumber()
    Rs_User.Requery
    Set Rs_User = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT userCode FROM tblUser ORDER BY userCode"
    Rs_User.Open strSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    If Rs_User.BOF Then
        NewCode = "CDEUSR001"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Rs_User.MoveLast
        NewCode = Rs_User!userCode
        userCode = Right(userCode, 3)
        userCode = Val(userCode) + 1
        If Len(userCode) > 5 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    userCode = "CDEUSR" & Format(NewCode, "000")
 End Sub
```

this is my VB.NET(VB2012) code, when the add button, it will show CDEUSER001, not display CDEUSR005.[Image sample that wont' works in VB.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cj8m.png)

```
Sub autoNumber()
    sql = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT userCode FROM tblUser ORDER BY userCode", conn)
    dr = sql.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    If (xxxx which has same function with Rs_User.BOF) Then
        NewCode = "CDEUSR001"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        NewCode = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(dr.GetString(0), 3)
        NewCode = Val(NewCode) + 1
        If Len(NewCode) > 5 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    NewCode = "CDEUSR" & Format(NewCode, "000")
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a database then why aren't you letting it generate the numbers?

Comment: Your code should work, obviously condition  `If (xxxx which has same function with Rs_User.BOF) Then` always returns `true` in your case.

Comment: @jmcilhinney:i don't know how to do it.......

Comment: @Fabio: hihi...VB.NET slighlty difference.....

Comment: It seems like this is a table that holds a single row and that you are wanting to see if anything was returned from the query (meaning start at CDEUSR001) otherwise add 1 to the numeric value of the existing number. In this case you would just check to see if the reader .hasrows and if false use your starting number, otherwise, break down and increment the number. If i'm not assuming correctly, then consider querying the LAST userCode from the table and work from there.

Comment: @CharlesMay: yes, it's correct, but when i use prev code (VB6 version) in VB.net.. failed to work....

Answer (score 0):

The difference between ADODB in VB6 and `OdbcConnection` in VB.NET is that `OdbcConnection` often uses `OdbcDataReader.HasRows` property as `ADODB.Recordset.BOF` or `ADODB.Recordset.EOF` counterpart.

Your VB.NET code should be modified as this (`Using` block added as common convention when initializing `OdbcConnection`):

```vb
Sub autoNumber()
    Using conn As New OdbcConnection(...)
        Using sql As New OdbcCommand("SELECT userCode FROM tblUser ORDER BY userCode", conn)
           Using dr As OdbcDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader()

               ' similar like Recordset.EOF or BOF
               If dr.HasRows = False Then 
                   NewCode = "CDEUSR001"
                   Exit Sub
               Else
                   dr.Read()
                   ' dr("userCode") may also work here
                   NewCode = Right(dr.GetString(0), 3)
                   NewCode = Val(NewCode) + 1
                   If Len(NewCode) > 5 Then
                      Exit Sub
                   End If
               End If
            NewCode = "CDEUSR" & Format(NewCode, "000")
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note: Unlike `ADODB.Recordset`, `OdbcDataReader` doesn't have row indexing to determine last row, but `DataSet` does. You can retrieve the last record in `DataSet` as given below:

```vb
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

Using conn As New OdbcConnection(...)
   Using sql As New OdbcCommand("SELECT userCode FROM tblUser ORDER BY userCode", conn)
       Dim adapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sql)
       adapter.Fill(ds)

       ' here to get last row from DataSet
       ' related: stackoverflow.com/questions/2099379/
       NewCode = Right(ds.Tables(0)(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("userCode"), 3)

       ' other stuff

   End Using
End Using
```